# Typo3 Canonical URL in Plugin Pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a typo3 Plugin (my own) which have lots of sub pages.

Now all Pages got their own canonical URL ... but I want that they only have the canonical from the page which contains the Plugin.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you really think it a good idea to have one URL with multiple content?  
what should be indexed for that URL? maybe you misunderstand the term "canonical URL"?

Comment: its not really multiple content. Normal behaviour of a plugin, Posts and gets ... so URL is changed and params are added. 

so the page should get a single canonical ... now the page got the canonícal with params. changed every click on the page.

Comment: it always adds this: `uebersicht/videotrainings-ansehen/?tx_institutsvideoverwaltung_videoverwaltungfrontend%5Bvideo%5D=155&amp;tx_institutsvideoverwaltung_videoverwaltungfrontend%5Baction%5D=show&amp;tx_institutsvideoverwaltung_videoverwaltungfrontend%5Bcontroller%5D=FrontendVideo&amp;cHash=5c6a11fb5cd2ceebab61d46645d24bb4"` as canonical .... thats not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the content changes with the parameters these parameters belong to the canonical URL.

You might not want your parameter specified pages indexed, but that needs other metatags than a non unique canonical url.

A canonical URL is used to have a unique URL for a page which can be accessed with multiple URLs. So Search engines know which URL to use and don't think of duplicate content.

---

If you really want to fool search engines with multiple content for the same URL you can of cause generate the base URL without all parameters and use it as canonical URL. Mind the value of `config.linkVars`. Just build your meta tag by hand using `page.headerData`.